# Python WOS search function TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python

Trying to conduct automated downloads from Web of Science with python wos library. 
Throws an error that seems to be coming from the wos package, but I'm unsure.

Have tried messing around in the underlying library, but this seems like bad practice.

```
x='my query'

with WosClient( lite=True) as client:
    client.connect()
    wos.utils.query(client, str(x))


Authenticated (SID: 6CZsG4iKOFMUq2UCu9N)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-093a8e409039> in <module>
      1 with WosClient( lite=True) as client:
      2     client.connect()
----> 3     wos.utils.query(client, str(x))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wos\utils.py in query(wosclient, wos_query, xml_query, count, offset, limit)
     22     """Query Web of Science and XML query results with multiple requests."""
     23     results = [single(wosclient, wos_query, xml_query, min(limit, count-x+1), x)
---> 24                for x in range(offset, count+1, limit)]
     25     if xml_query:
     26         return [el for res in results for el in res]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wos\utils.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     22     """Query Web of Science and XML query results with multiple requests."""
     23     results = [single(wosclient, wos_query, xml_query, min(limit, count-x+1), x)
---> 24                for x in range(offset, count+1, limit)]
     25     if xml_query:
     26         return [el for res in results for el in res]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wos\utils.py in single(wosclient, wos_query, xml_query, count, offset)
     11     """Perform a single Web of Science query and then XML query the results."""
     12     result = wosclient.search(wos_query, count, offset)
---> 13     xml = _re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', result.records, count=1).encode('utf-8')
     14     if xml_query:
     15         xml = _ET.fromstring(xml)

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    190     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    191     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 192     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    193 
    194 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```